# Placing and using css and js files in spring

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-mvc

I'm a newbie to spring mvc I have developed all the basic things based on the tutorials in tutorials point, but it does not explain how to link the css files or js files. I have gone through other questions regarding this in stackoverflow but I could not solve my problem. First I'll start with the error given below.

```
GET http://localhost:8082/Springtest/resources/css/bootstrap.css
```

My **web.xml** is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"> 
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name> 
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Springtest</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 
 <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>Springtest</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="Student" /> 
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> 
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
</bean>
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 
</beans>
```

**Springtest-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 
<context:component-scan base-package="Student" /> 
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> 
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
</bean>
</beans>
```

I have linked to my css using the statement below

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

The image of the file structure used is below.

[image: File Structure of my project]

I have marked the position where my css files are included, I have not used maven or pom.xml. Please tell me what is the mistake I have made here. I also don't know the use of maven and pom.xml in spring-mvc project so a tutorial to that also will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am using TheamLeaf instead of Jsp in Spring MVC, & I add this line in every page before use this CSS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/frontend/css/myStyle.css}" />
```

similar case with my own custom JavaScript file

```
<script th:src="@{/custom/js/myFile.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Would you try this? I mean have you these link in your Jsp page?

Comment: You need to go this url
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Answer (score 0):

I think in the resource tag should be

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

or you should declare it

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: I still have the same error, it must be something else.